# ASP.NET runtime error: "path" is not a valid IIS application. VS2012 / IIS7.5

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

A strange behavior with my ASP.net mvc 4 application running under IIS7.5.

Every time I rebuild the application, 2 applications appears on IIS filetree node of my project.
The first one is fine. It is a application I have create. 
The second one is another that should not be present.

I have renamed my application and I believe there is no more reference of the old name.

The old name was Gedi.

Today I was trying for the first time the publish tool from visual studio and I got this warning:

`Warning    1 C:\Users\Guilherme\Documents\Visual Studio` `2012\Projects\gedaiapp\gedaiapp\Views\Operacao\opImportacaoConfig.cshtml:`

```
ASP.NET runtime error: '/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/Gedi' is not a valid IIS application.

C:\Users\Guilherme\Documents\Visual Studio
2012\Projects\gedaiapp\gedaiapp\Views\Operacao\opImportacaoConfig.cshtml
1   1   gedaiapp
```

I don't understand where this Gedi still exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the Web section of the project properties in Visual Studio.  If you've got it set to use local IIS and this is still pointing at your old location, it's probably what's causing it to reappear each time you build.